# Excel: Flashfill Offset Horizontal + Vertical

Tags: excel, offset

So I'm not a fan of VBA and I recently learned that OFFSET can be used with COUNTA to flashfill a range as far at it is as long as you aim for a longer range than you have data. Now I want to be able to achieve this both for columns and rows at the same time, where the rows are averaged. Could this be done? I am banging my head against the wall to find some logic to do it, but can only manage to combine it in a way that multiplies the rows with the number of the column.. which is not desired, of course.

I have posted a Minimal Reproducible Example in Excel Online:
https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=63EC0594BD919535!1491&ithint=file%2cxlsx&authkey=!ALmV0VtFb7QZCvI

If you see Cell J9 and J11 you will see what I want to combine. The three rows in J11 and down, I want to average in J10, and spill/flashfill (like J9 and 11 does automatically because of the formula already) them from to the right, for as many columns as there data in the range A1-G4..

So I have raw data of *numbers* with titles in A1-G4, and by writing `=OFFSET($A$1:$A$1,0,0,1,COUNTA($A$1:$EV$1)-1)` in J9 I get all the titles of the columns filled from left to right, and by writing `=OFFSET($A$1,1,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1)` in J11 I get the rows of the first column filled from top to bottom. They can also be combined, by writing `OFFSET(Days,1,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1,COUNTA(Days))`, where "Days" is `=OFFSET($A$1:$A$1,0,0,1,COUNTA($A$1:$EV$1)-1)` (in a named range for readability) or `OFFSET($A$1:$A$1,0,0,1,COUNTA($A$1:$EV$1)-1)` without using a named range

As a thought, though I'm not sure how to implement it, maybe this could somehow be used in some form to get the column reference for the horizontal part in combination with `=AVERAGE(OFFSET($A$1,1,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1))`

```
=MID(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),2,SEARCH("$",ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),2)-2)
```

..found at https://superuser.com/questions/1259506/formula-to-return-just-the-column-letter-in-excel/1259507

Comment: Hi Mate, I downloaded a copy of your file trying to figure out what is your issue, see that `If you see Cell J9 and J11 you will see what I want to combine. The three rows in J11 and down, I want to average in J10` doesn't make sense as **You are useing twice J11**. Could you explain to me please?

Comment: @TsiriniainaRakotonirina hi! So, J9 is an example of how an offset formula can be entered to get the titles of the headers in my data automatically expand to the right, for as many columns as there are titles (a "for loop" if you will - if you look to programming languages for iteration) - by just entering the formula in J9. J11 is the same, only that it repeats vertically. My desired result is to enter a formula in J10 that takes the average of J11 (so think of it as wrapping the formula in J11 with an average() formula), but then also have the effect of the formula in J9, meaning I want..

Comment: ..the average of what J11 is getting, iterated for as many columns of data that there is. All with one formula, in one cell: J10. As Excel formulas are not a full fledged programming language has so called "for loops" built in, I'm not sure it's possible, but then again, algorithms/advanced logic is not my strong suit. That's why I am asking, so that if it is possible, I might also be able to understand it and utilize the logic not only for this, but maybe even to understand other complex concepts.

Comment: I do also have a feeling that the formula in J21 might be a part of the key to unlocking the result I want, as it does not return the title of the columns, but rather the column names, meaning it might be possible to work it in as indirect references somehow: `=MID(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(OFFSET($A$1:$A$1,0,0,1,COUNTA($A$1:$EV$1)-1))),2,SEARCH("$",ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(OFFSET($A$1:$A$1,0,0,1,COUNTA($A$1:$EV$1)-1))),2)-2)` _(could be cleaned up by using named references of course)_

Comment: In summary, if I understood you well:
`- J9:N9 is getting its value from A1:E1`
`- J11:NXX is getting its value from A2:EXX` (And the rows expands)
`- J10:N10 is supposed to be the average of J11:NXX`

Isn't it?

Comment: Or to try to explain it in plain English (as another perspective I guess): "For as many columns that there are column titles, I want to average their data/rows individually, by entering a formula in J10, and only in J10, having Excel auto-populating as many cells to the right, as there are columns"

Comment: Now my second question is, I see several sheets within the sample. Do you want to replicate this with several same worksheets within the Workbook or only for one single sheet but you copied several times for testing please?

Comment: @TsiriniainaRakotonirina exactly. Well, only that right now J11:J13 is getting it from A2:A4, K10:K13 from B2:B4 and so on. Otherwise exactly

Comment: @TsiriniainaRakotonirina the number of sheets are just there for people to try it out without wrecking the original, as someone did when I first posted it. Leaving the example useless for others to see. The pitfall of only having one example sheet for someone to ruin I guess (:

Comment: Now, since the average is the most important for you, is it really necessary that whatever is in A1:Exxx be replicated on J9:Nxxx? `(Because A1:Exxx is expanding, so J9:Nxxx as well will have to expand)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211251/discussion-between-tsiriniaina-rakotonirina-and-streching-my-competence).

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but i find really hard to understand what you are looking for. I understood that: 1. you don't want VBA (user-made subroutines/functions); 2. you don't want Tabel (or you are just saying it won't do the trick?); 3. you need one formulas in J10 with the average of the column A; 4. one can autofill said formula into the cells of row 10 (like K10, L10, ect...) and its result will be the average of the next columns (like K10 woud gives you the average of column B, L10 column C, ect..); 5. column A, B, C... will (or just might?) have numbers as headers in the first row, so the s

Comment: 1) correct. 2) won't do the trick, it's not the data range per say I need to expand as it does, but the result of it (an average of each column for as many columns as there are) 3) One formula in J10 for the average of A, B, C, D etc. in J10, K10, L10 etc. Only formula in J10 though. 4) How to autofill that formula is the core question. 5) Correct

Comment: ok, i've written down something. To go on i have to ask:

 1. is column A the only one that will have values external to the data we need to calculate?
 2. will all the cells in the data range (in this case A2:E4) be filled with data?

Comment: Wait: you need it to autofill without the user to drag it and without any macro? You want a formula to appear from nothing? Because i don't think you can autofill and empty cell without macro or without the user actively dragging it.

Comment: if you see the example file, it is possible to autofill without dragging, both vertically and horizontally, which leads me to believe there is a way to combine those two, as long as you apply the right logic (which is what I am struggling with). Open the example file in Excel online and try either `=OFFSET($A$1,1,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1)` or `=OFFSET($A$1:$A$1,0,0,1,COUNTA($A$1:$EV$1)-1)` to see it happen. For it to work in the application itself, you might have to have 2019 or 365, I cannot really test in earlier versions. It may work in 2016 and up though

Comment: I kept on trying and searching. I have Excel 2016 and it seems to me what you are looking for is dynamic array formula with spilled array behavior. Such feature is not implemented in Excel 2016 (and i didn't knew it existed in the first place). Moreover the online file you have shared is limited, so i can't really test any solution myself (and the examples i've tested didn't work even though they should have according to what i've found). I've looked for a list of dynamic function with spilled array behavior and those i've found were clearly incomplete since the OFFSET function [CONTINUE]

Comment: [...] wasn't mentioned. Any other example of the use of AVERAGE function didn't have a spilled array behaviour. You still had to manually autofill it. Therefore i'm afraid i can't help you.

Comment: I know I'm late to this interesting post, and not sure If I understand properly, but in the Excel online you've provided, there is a part that says `J10 should result in: 401,6666667
` and I just want to say that your actual formula already does that, and it returns the number you want, but you have to change the format of the cell to show decimals (your actual cell format is set to show 0 decimals), so where is the problem?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGEQm.png

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns it also says "K10 should result in:", "L10 should reuslt in:" and so on. It's not a decimal/formatting issue at all. The text on row 16 is simply a key for the wanted end result - the formatting of the result is not in question whatsoever. If you're interested, please read my previous explanation of the issue and this should be clear.

Answer (score 2):

Now, based on your explanation, here is the screenshot of my test:

[image]

### Section A1:Exxx

I have converted that section into a Table, called **«TblData»**, having numerous avantages:

1. It expands automatically without any additional efforts/formula
2. We can identify Data by its Columns attributed automatically by the Table `[@1], [@2],[@3], [@4], [@5]`

### Section J9:N9

As a replica of the table name, I have used the following formula to retrieve it:

```
=INDEX(TblData[#Headers],1,COLUMN(A1))    '<--- This is for J9
=INDEX(TblData[#Headers],1,COLUMN(E1))    '<--- This is for N9
```

### Section J11:Nxx

As a replica of the Table Content, I have used the following formula to populate the content:

```
=INDEX(TblData,ROW($A1),MATCH(J$9,TblData[#Headers],0))   '<--- This is on J11
=INDEX(TblData,ROW($A3),MATCH(N$9,TblData[#Headers],0))   '<--- This is on N13
```

### Section J10:N10

Now this is the interesting part of the **Average**, so here is the formula I used for it:

```
=AVERAGE(TblData[1])  '<--- This is on J10
=AVERAGE(TblData[5])  '<--- This is on N10
```

> NB: **(1)** Instead of using the Content below J10:N10, I prefer to reuse the Table as it expands automatically as more rows are added.
>   **(2)** Unless it is really necessary, I feel it is a double work as well to replicate again A1:Exxx from J9:Nxxx, because you can use the Table for whatever you need, with less maintenance.

Kindly find attached the file as well after I updated those items:

> File Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wRbpUxg0XLpfGqdvMF4fNKXDrL7xPPWs

We can correspond more below for further info. Hoping you to strech more your compentence :)

Comment: the benefits of a Table is fine, though unfortunately for this example it will not work, as even though the table expands, you will have to expand the result manually - meaning that if a new column is added to the data, then you will have to write `=AVERAGE(TblData[6])` in O10 and so on. This is the very thing I want to avoid so I can always guarantee the all the results are included without manual adjustments. This is more of an experiment to see if it is possible to iterate both ways, treating the calc of the average in each iteration seperately somehow..

Comment: ..as if when working in a programming language, for example JavaScript where you have a "For Loop". I would if I had access to using programming languages that I know, though I do not due to the work environment (which means VBA is out of the question for yet another reason than being unreliable for documents with multiple users, many inexperienced).

Comment: If you keep your structure and still use the `J9:N13`, with the Table and the formula I gave you, you can now change the **Average** formula to be `=AVERAGE(J11:J13)` [Formula in J10] and `=AVERAGE(N11:N13)` [Formula in N10] because formula on `J9:N9` uses alreay the formula `=INDEX(TblData[#Headers],1,COLUMN(A1))`  to search for your Column. **You to not need to do anything** except adding the Column in the right only.

Comment: Below is an update of what I shared with you where I added new Columns and see by yourself if it works. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wRbpUxg0XLpfGqdvMF4fNKXDrL7xPPWs

Comment: I completely understand that. However, having to copy to the right is the core of this problem, so having to do it cannot be a solution to it. I have no trouble solving this in a multitude of ways where the end result is having to copy to the right in the end.

Comment: I guess the easiest would be to count the number of columns in one cell, and use `=OFFSET($A$1,1,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1)` in J10, only removing the $'s to allow for column stepping when copied to the right and pasting as a formula, then create a VBA macro that repeats the copying to the right for as many columns as the column count says there are columns. Then again, a VBA script does not adjust cell references when the file is updated, which also means constant maintenance as it will be a living document that needs adjustment for different data sources and also when junior users use it..

Comment: ..they will not be able to troubleshoot an error thrown due to incorrect references in the VBA, should they change something vital in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, mate, I can't figure out what you want to calculate. If it makes sense to add J9+J11 then you could just concatenate the two formulas in J9 and J11 with a plus sign. After much deliberation I decided to assume that your question is not one of formula but of formula-writing - "referencing" for short. Therefore I prepared this answer for you, hoping that it will prove helpful.

Building on your named range *Days* I suggest you create a dynamic named range *Data* with this formula.
[Data] `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),COUNTA(Sheet1!$1:$1))`

The range thus defined is dynamic in both directions. However, bearing in mind that OFFSET is volatile (slows down your worksheet) you may like to keep its use limited to this one formula and perhaps start the range at A2, but I shall tempt you to break the rule. Now you can use the INDEX function to refer to the `Data` range.

`= INDEX(Data, [Row number], [Column number])`
defines a single cell. But by setting either column or row to zero you can define an entire column or row. `=INDEX(Data,0,1)` defines column 1 of the *Data* range, `=INDEX(Data,1,0)` defines its first row. 
`=INDEX(OFFSET(Data,1,0),0,1)` defines the first column of a range moved down by one row from its original position. I recommend the alternative and start the *Data* range from A2 and perhaps declare another range for the first row if needed.

`=AVERAGE(INDEX(Data,0,1))` would draw the same average you already have in your sheet, provided that Data was defined starting at A2. For fun's sake, `=AVERAGE(INDEX(OFFSET(Data,1,0),0,1))` would do the same without the change in the range's definition.

`=COLUMN()` returns the number of the column this formula resides in. So, you could enter `=COLUMN()-6` in column G, copy to the right and get a count starting from 1. (You can do the same vertically with the ROW() function.) Applied to your formula, `=AVERAGE(INDEX(Data,0,COLUMN()-6))` would return the average from column 1 if entered in column G, and from columns 2, 3 4, etc as copied to the right.

As I said, I don't understand enough of your request to bring this idea to a conclusion but I think that using the method described above will provide you with a tool to copy formulas into the table your sample has at its right. If you would elaborate on your requirement I might be able to assist more.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is a combination of J9 and J11, that is, only enter a formula in J10 that automatically fills to the right (so I don't have to copy to the right manually, as the number of columns with data changes every time I work with my sheet). The same goes for rows - so that is why I want to use offset to get all the data in one column, but also offset to expand to as many columns as I have data. I do not want to use a pivot or VBA, as a pivot requires manual refresh and can be forgotten, and VBA is easily broken by unexperienced users of my sheet.

Comment: I only want one calculation of this, so the fact that offset is slowing down the sheet really does not matter much as it will be a relatively low sample size of data also.

Comment: You are just repeating what I already don't understand. The way forward is to use the formula I have supplied and then tell me at which point it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: `=INDEX(OFFSET(Data,1,0),0,1)`, or `=INDEX(OFFSET(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A),COUNTA($1:$1)),1,0),0,1)` written out, gives me row 1-4 of data, so one more row than there is data. `=OFFSET($A$1,1,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1)` which I use now, does not, it gives only the rows of data there is vertically in column A. That means the formula you suggested of `=AVERAGE(INDEX(OFFSET(Data,1,0),0,1))` does the same, compared to `=AVERAGE(OFFSET($A$1,1,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1))` that I already use. And..

Comment: `=AVERAGE(INDEX(Data,0,COLUMN()-6))` takes the average of column 5 or E, including the title. So if the title is 5, and the data rows are 754, 774 and 650, you land on an average of 545.75 instead of 726.Have you looked at my example? I don't know how to explain it in a better way. I want to enter a formula cell J10, and want it to take the average of column A and put it in that cell, then I want K10 to be the average of column B, L10 to be the average of column C and so on, without ever having to enter a formula in any other cell than J10.. just like your examples expand down, I also

Comment: I think it's like I suspected. My formula, using `COLUMN()-9` can be pasted from J10 to the right and down just as you want. But you want it to AutoFill. With that, I regret, I can't help you. I'm on Excel 2013 and neither have that functionality, nor am I familiar with it. I was hoping, once you have the formula you would know how to apply it. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: ok. then it may be hard to achieve (due to versions). Also, I'm sorry I never specified that J9 and J11 is only examples of what I want to combine. The end result is reliant on J9 and J11 never existing.